# declare dynamic array based on dynamic variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

This an array

```
 ARRAY = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
 var mlength = ARRAY.length;
```

Depending on `mlength` the length of `DATES` must be declared. Here the length is 5. Hence the array DATES must be  `var DATES = [[], [], [], [], []];` similarly if array ARRAY length is 3 then `var DATES = [[], [], []]`

This is static declaration. How do I declare it based upon the array `ARRAY` length?

Comment: How are you declaring these variables? I feel you're trying to solve this the wrong way...

Comment: Why not just store your values in one nested array?

Comment: I have edited my code. I just want to declare an empty array. Later I will push the values into it. That is a different coding. Only the size of array depends on the number of variables

Comment: Use an object , really better way to do this

Comment: @rjirji but the size doesn't matter at all, if you are only pushing values onto it.

Comment: _“I am declaring the variables in this way”_ – so you already _have_ an array to begin with, then you want to generate variables with numbers in their names _from that_ – only to then generate an array out of those _again_? I can’t see how that is supposed to make sense really. (Btw., whenever the thought of using “variables with numbers in their names” crosses your mind, that is a pretty sure indicator that you went wrong right there already.)

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you have data values of an identical structure or meaning, using an array is appropriate. If they _don’t_ have an identical structure or meaning – then what they represents is obviously so different, that better variable names than `fooA`,`fooB`,`fooC` or `bar1`,`bar2`,`bar3` … should have been chosen in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is easy:

```
var DATES=[];for (var i=0;i<mlength;DATES.push([]),i++);
```

Just push an empty array to `DATES` `mlength` number of times.

Comment: Forget everything. Please see the question again. I have changed it completely

Comment: "Please see the question again. I have changed it completely" This is considered bad form on SO, by the way. If you are tempted to change your question that much, create a new question, and delete this one if necessary.

Comment: @theonlygusti - I got it thanq :)

Comment: @theonlygusti - Can you do me one more favour? How do I declare MARKETS[i].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname+i, month)) || null); in the same manner where i=mlength here MARKETS[i] and mname+i are to be replaced by i in for loop

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```
ARRAY = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var mlength = ARRAY.length,
    DATES = [];

    DATES.length = mlength;
    DATES.fill([]);
    //DATES is now -> [ [], [], [], [], [], ]
```

Comment: It should be noted this depends on the array having a `fill` method, which is an ES6 feature not implemented in all browsers (specifically, not in IE). See [this compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Array.prototype_methods) for more information.

Comment: Wouldn't this create the sub-array only once, and assign its reference to every slot of DATES?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - its not working. I will show you the complete code. see this link its not working. I will show you my complete code. see this link jsfiddle.net/xbk57jdo/5 in line 111

Comment: @rjirji, I'm not sure why you're pinging me about it. I wrote that comment to tell you (and everyone else) that the code most likely would not work, so it's not surprising to me that it does, in fact, not work.